# How to replace a special character in email body with a value in each row using Excel with VBA to multiple recipients

Tags: email, vba, replace

I am creating an Excel UserForm that creates a separate email for up to 500 recipients.

There are 4 columns on the worksheet: Name(Column A), Email(Column B), Value 1(Column C).

The code uses the For and Next loop style, where r is declared as an Integer (r = 2 To 500) and with the MailItem Object, .To =Cells(r,2).

The issue I have is attempting to incorporate values from a range (Column C) that replace special characters placed in the text box used to create the body of the email.

So if I were to type, `Hello, There were ^&^ transactions that failed yesterday.` and hit a command button used for "Send", it would send an email to the each email address listed in Column B and replace `^&^` with the value in Column C to each individual email address (each row).

Below is the VBA code as an example.  There are a lot of other declared variables that I did not mention of course to keep this inquiry as short as possible.

```
Dim Signature As String, EmailSensitivity As String, EmailImportance As String
Dim Greeting As String, Punctuation As String, Security As String

Sub SendButton1_Click()
If SubjectText = vbNullString Then
If EmailBody1 = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Form Incomplete:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "No Subject or Email Text.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If
End If

If SubjectText = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Form Incomplete:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "Please enter Subject.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

If EmailBody1 = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Form Incomplete:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "Please enter Email Text."
    Exit Sub
End If

If SignatureText1 = vbNullString Then
    Continue = MsgBox("Your email contains no signature." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "Are you sure you wish to proceed?", vbYesNo)
        If Continue = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
End If



Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim r As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = 2 To 501

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .Subject = Security & SubjectText.Value
    .Body = EmailBody1.Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
     SignatureText1.Value
    .To = Cells(r, 2)
    .Attachements.Add AttachmentText1.Value
    .Importance = EmailImportance
    .Sensitivity = EmailSensitivity
    .Send
End With

Next r

Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheet1.Range("A2:B501").Clear

Continue = MsgBox("You have successfully generated a mass email!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
"Would you like to generate another email?", vbYesNo)
    If Continue = vbNo Then
        Application.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```

I am still an amateur, so I'm working on cleaning a lot of unnecessary code, but this inquiry is mainly on replacing the special character with the value listed in each row.

This is my first time actually posting an inquiry on a forum, so please let me know if I am not following the correct procedure as your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It might be as simple as this, using the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function:

```
...
With OutMail
    .Subject = Security & SubjectText.Value
    .Body = Replace(EmailBody1.Value,"^&^",Cells(r, 3)) & _
            vbCrLf & vbCrLf & SignatureText1.Value
...
```

Unrelated to this, but importat: `On Error Resume Next` means the sending (and any operation after that) will silently fail. This will make future debugging more difficult, frustrating and expensive. You should at least log relevant details about what error occured, and for what row in the sheet. And be sure to re-enable error-checking with `on error goto 0` or similar after the part of your program that might fail unexpectedly.